# Checking a specific card in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have create a list with a deck cards (first function). The first function creates a deck with 52 cards, with the second function I want to return the following values: the type of cards with value 5, the cards with Hearts symbol, and how many cards with Clubs symbol are in the deck.

When I run the function I get the following output:

> ['2 of Hearts', '3 of Hearts', '4 of Hearts', '5 of Hearts', '6 of
> Hearts', '7 of Hearts', '8 of Hearts', '9 of Hearts', '10 of Hearts',
> 'J of Hearts', 'Q of Hearts', 'K of Hearts', 'A of Hearts', '2 of
> Diamonds', '3 of Diamonds', '4 of Diamonds', '5 of Diamonds', '6 of
> Diamonds', '7 of Diamonds', '8 of Diamonds', '9 of Diamonds', '10 of
> Diamonds', 'J of Diamonds', 'Q of Diamonds', 'K of Diamonds', 'A of
> Diamonds', '2 of Spades', '3 of Spades', '4 of Spades', '5 of Spades',
> '6 of Spades', '7 of Spades', '8 of Spades', '9 of Spades', '10 of
> Spades', 'J of Spades', 'Q of Spades', 'K of Spades', 'A of Spades',
> '2 of Clubs', '3 of Clubs', '4 of Clubs', '5 of Clubs', '6 of Clubs',
> '7 of Clubs', '8 of Clubs', '9 of Clubs', '10 of Clubs', 'J of Clubs',
> 'Q of Clubs', 'K of Clubs', 'A of Clubs']
> Blockquote

What I think is happening is returning the whole deck of cards. Can someone help me with only returning:
the type of cards with value 5,
the cards with Hearts symbol,
and how many cards with Clubs symbol are in the deck.

Thank you

```
def make_cards():
        '''<YOUR DESCRIPTION GOES HERE>
    
        Tests
        >>> cards = make_cards()
        >>> len(cards)
        52
        >>> cards.count('3 of Diamonds')
        1
        >>> cards.count('Joker')
        0
        >>> 
        '''
        cards = []
        symbols = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"]
        values = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
    
        for symbol in symbols:
            for value in values:
                card = value + " of " + symbol
                cards.append(card)
        return cards
    
    def find_cards(deck, kind):
        '''<YOUR DESCRIPTION GOES HERE>
    
        Tests
        >>> deck = make_cards()
        >>> find_cards(deck, '5')
        ['5 of Hearts', '5 of Diamonds', '5 of Spades', '5 of Clubs']
        >>> find_cards(deck, 'Hearts')
        ['2 of Hearts', '3 of Hearts', '4 of Hearts', '5 of Hearts', '6 of Hearts', '7 of Hearts', '8 of Hearts', '9 of Hearts', '10 of Hearts', 'J of Hearts', 'Q of Hearts', 'K of Hearts', 'A of Hearts']
        >>> clubs = find_cards(deck, 'Clubs')
        >>> len(clubs)
        13
        '''
    
        deck = make_cards()
        card_Request = []
    
    
        for i in deck:
            for kind in deck:
                if (i == kind):
                    card_Request.append(i)
    
    
    
    
        return card_Request
```

Comment: `def find_cards(deck, kind):`   vs.    `for i in deck: for kind in deck:`  - what could possibly go wrong ... when you do `if (i == kind):`

Comment: I have tried it without the parenthesis and still have the same result

Comment: Which parameter specifically? I am getting kind from the function "def find_cards(deck, kind): "

Comment: no you dont. You get `kind` from your **inner loop**: `for kind in deck:`

Comment: I get it now, how could i get it from the function instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that you want to return the list all items that including "Hearts", all item that including "5" and number of item that including "Clubs". If it is true the code is following:

```
def make_cards():
    cards = []
    symbols = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"]
    values = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]

    for symbol in symbols:
        for value in values:
            card = value + " of " + symbol
            cards.append(card)
    return cards

def find_cards(type, amount, other_type):

    deck = make_cards()
    card_Request = []
    counter = 0

    for value in deck:
        if value.__contains__(type):
            card_Request.append(value)
        if value.__contains__(amount):
            card_Request.append(value)
        if value.__contains__(other_type):
            counter = counter + 1

    card_Request.append(counter)

    return card_Request



if __name__ == '__main__':
    card = find_cards("Hearts", "5", "Clubs ")
    print(card)
```

Important note : find_cards function returns a list that its last item represents number of "Clubs".

Comment: dunder methods should never be called directly - use `if amount in value:` instead.  `type` as name is already used by a built in `type()` - you should avoid shadowning built ins.